# Why are html taglines not working in my android app?

Tags: java, android

I have a textview in my xml and I'm setting the contents of the textview in my java class. Whenever I set my text to something like

```
"<b>Thermodynamic Properties</b>"+"\n"
```

or

```
"<b>Thermodynamic Properties"+"</b>\n"
```

the app will show the text as:

< b>Thermodynamic Properties< /b>

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What output do you want it should be?

Comment: `String text = "Hi!<br/>I am...";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));`

Comment: Thanks! That solution works, but now I have to change all of my \n to <br> lol.

Comment: `text = text.replaceAll("\n", "<br/>");` :)